# Excel VBA: Could not set the list property error for coworkers comp.. However it works on mine?

Tags: vba, excel

All,

I've recently built a worksheet mostly run by VBA macros (built in Excel 2007).  One of the functions of this sheet is that when a user clicks a button, it runs a macro which populates a listbox in a form, then shows the form and allows them to do a couple things related to that list.

This macro works fine on my computer and also for 3 or 4 other users' computers that I've tested it on in my office.

However, when a user located in Poland tries to use it, he receives a 'Could not set the list property. Type Mismatch' error when he clicks the button.

He's using Office 2010 Plus.  I've tested this on a coworkers computer in my office who's also using 2010 and it worked fine.

The user getting the error *does* appear to be using a Polish version of excel, so I'm not sure if this is contributing to the problem?  The following is the code that's returning the error:

```
Sub AccountAssignmentChange()
count = 0
AssignAccounts.ExecName.Caption = "Account Management for " _
    & ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value
For i = 2 To 9
    If Not Sheet1.Cells(i, 33) = "" Then
        With AssignAccounts.RegionBox
            .AddItem
            .List(count) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 33)
            count = count + 1
        End With
    End If
Next
AssignAccounts.Show
End Sub
```

For clarification, Activesheet.Range("D4").value is an employee name.  Sheet1.Cells(i,33) (for 2 to 9) is a range containing region names that get populated into the list box.

The employee getting the error has access to one region (this means the list box should be populated with one item).  I've changed my access to only that region and had no problems.  Also did so for the user using 2010 in my office and it worked fine for him.

[Also, here is a screenshot of the error the employee sent me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7UYU.jpg)

Any ideas?  Pretty lost with this error.

EDIT: I now have an (I'm assuming) unrelated development.  This particular employee is now receiving an error stating "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action".

I'm also stumped on why this error is getting thrown.  For info: There's a macro that runs on workbook open that opens another worksheet that sits on a shared drive.  The shared drive is already mapped to this employee's computer, so that's not an issue.

The workbook being accessed remotely is a shared workbook because multiple people may be using this worksheet at the same time.

This employee is receiving the OLE error when the macro tries to open the workbook.  When he hits 'OK' the notification stays there and effectively hangs.

I have no idea why this is happening.  I thought there might be a problem with two people trying to access the shared workbook at the same time, but I tested this with a couple coworkers located in my office, and it worked without issue.

Any ideas on this?  This particular employee is having issues that totally stump me.

Comment: First step would be to properly declare all of your variables. `Dim i As Long, count As Long`. Also, use `Option Explicit` in this module. Also, if possible, upload a new screenshot but do *not* white out the VB project explorer and let's see what the internal identifier of the Worksheet Objects look like, perhaps `Sheet1` is not valid in Polish?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `Sheet1.Cells(i, 33)` when the error is raised?

Comment: Try specifying `.List(count) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 33).Value` to ensure that it isn't trying to make the .List(Count) equal the range object instead.

Comment: Can you run the code in the debugger on the colleague's machine - then you could put in a breakpoint and look at the variables in the watch window. I think @DavidZemens may be right that there is a problem with `Sheet1`. What if you create a variable `Dim sh as Sheet`, see if you can `Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")`, and replace `Sheet1` with `sh`... it's a curious error!

Comment: @DavidZemens: VB project explorer is whited out because some of the tab names are employee names.  I can confirm that the internal identifiers align with the english version (ie: I see sheet1 etc in the whited out space of the project explorer).  Also, there are a few other macros that run prior to him getting to the point where he presses this button.  They make use of sheet codenames with no issue.

The value of Sheet1.Cells(i, 33) is "SEUR" (a string).

Comment: Per Matt's suggestion try `.List(count) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 33).Value` or `.List(count) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 33).Text`?

Comment: @Floris: Unfortunately the colleague is in Poland (I'm in London) and has no knowledge of VBA.  I could potentially do this but it would be a big effort (would have to take control of his desktop remotely etc) and I would prefer to avoid it if possible.  Also, there are other macros that refer to Sheet1.Cells(i, 33) that run when the workbook opens... Strangely they work fine... so I'm not sure how that value could be the source of the issue

Comment: `If Not Sheet1.Cells(i, 33) = "" Then` should probably be rewritten as `if Sheet1.cells(i,33) <> "" then`

Comment: Also worth trying `.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 33).Value`. The `.AddItem` method automatically puts the new item at the end of the list. The line `.List(count) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 33)` is redundant.

Comment: I will make the suggested changes and send it over to the coworker... maybe the .value identifier was the problem

I'll respond as soon as he gets back to me

Comment: I've updated the original question (everything past Edit:) as the employee in question is now having a new problem which I find equally confusing.

I'm not sure how much traffic this question will get, so I may post a new question to address the issue as I believe it's unrelated to the original problem anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below (edited) code. You need to keep in mind that ListBoxes are like grids, the .List property takes a Column and Row parameter... i.e. .List(1, 0)... 
 ALSO - make sure that the user in Poland has the reference **(Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library)** added to his workbook...

```
Sub AccountAssignmentChange()
count = 0
AssignAccounts.ExecName.Caption = "Account Management for " _
    & ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value
For i = 2 To 9
    If Not Sheet1.Cells(i, 33) = "" Then
        With AssignAccounts.RegionBox
            .AddItem 0 'Speficy the list reference (top) 
            .List(count, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 33) 'Call the correct list...
            count = count + 1
        End With
    End If
Next
AssignAccounts.Show
End Sub
```